# How to define optional field in OMG IDL struct?

Tags: corba, idl

Is optional field supported in IDL defined by OMG?
If not, is using sequence or fixed size array to wrap it a good practice?
Or just leave it to be null at the runtime without further hint at the IDL specification?

Answer (score 3):

The [OMG IDL 4.2 specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/IDL) does define an `@optional` annotation to indicate that a field is optional but this is not supported by CORBA. The best practice is to use an IDL sequence.